# sed command not accepting sub-string with '.' in ksh

Tags: linux, sed, ksh

I am writing a ksh script which processes a path variable containing `@sys` substring to its corresponding OS name:

If `build_type` is is of 64bit version we need to append `.64` at the end of `osver`.

e.g. if `opsys=amd64_linux26_rh5`(Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5) and `build_type=dbg64`, `osver` should be `amd64_linux26_rh5.64`.

Now, I want to replace `@sys` present in `file_path` variable with its corresponding OS version as a substring i.e. `amd64_linux26_rh5.64`.

But it looks like `sed` is ignoring . somehow and the only `amd64_linux26_rh5` is replacing `@sys` omitting the `.64` part.

```
#!/bin/ksh
file_path="/xxx/xxx/xxx/@sys/xxx"
sys="@sys"
bld_type="dbg64"
opsys="amd64_linux26_rh5"
bitver=".64"
if [[ ${bld_type} = @(*64) ]]
then
    osver="${opsys}${bitver}"
fi
echo "osver: $osver"
echo "old file_path is : $file_path"
file_path=$(echo "$file_path" | sed "s/$sys/${osver}/")
echo "new file_path is : $file_path"
```

The corrosponding output:

```
osver: amd64_linux26_rh5.64
old file_path is : /xxx/xxx/xxx/amd64_linux26_rh5/xxx
new file_path is : /xxx/xxx/xxx/amd64_linux26_rh5/xxx
```

We are trying to change `file_path` to `/xxx/xxx/xxx/amd64_linux26_rh5.64/xxx`. Please suggest an appropriate way use `sed` in this case.

Comment: I'm getting a different output.

Comment: @choroba, Can you please share the output?

Comment: `osver: amd64_linux26_rh5.64` \n `old file_path is : /xxx/xxx/xxx/@sys/xxx` \n `new file_path is : /xxx/xxx/xxx/amd64_linux26_rh5.64/xxx`.

Comment: @choroba, I think for me its `parameter interpolation` of `ksh`.

Comment: I copied the script including the shebang line, so it's ksh here, too.

Comment: Like @choroba, it works for me. What version of sed/ksh? You could use to bypass sed `echo "new file_path is : ${file_path/@sys/${osver}}"`

Comment: Can you break it down like `sys="@sys";file_path="/xxx/xxx/xxx/@sys/xxx";
osver="amd64_linux26_rh5.64";echo "${file_path}" | sed "s/${sys}/${osver}/"` ? I see a path with `.64`.

Answer (score 2):

When the output shows

```
old file_path is : /xxx/xxx/xxx/amd64_linux26_rh5/xxx
```

then something went wrong in copy-pasting the code.
In your code the `file_path` is set to

```
file_path="/xxx/xxx/xxx/@sys/xxx"
```

and is never changed before the `echo`. So your code seems to be different from what you show.
When you start after the

```
 echo "old file_path is : $file_path"
```

the output makes sense.
In your sed command

```
file_path=$(echo "$file_path" | sed "s/$sys/${osver}/")
```

sed will not find `@sys` in the string `/xxx/xxx/xxx/amd64_linux26_rh5/xxx`, and the `old_string` remains unchanged.