# Using sed to replace string with another string containing special character in ksh

Tags: sed, special-characters, ksh

I am trying to replace `@sys` with `amd64_linux26_rh5.64` with sed command.

```
#!/bin/ksh
file_path="/xxx/xxx/xxx/@sys/xxx"
os="amd64_linux26_rh5"
osver="amd64_linux26_rh5.64"
sys="@sys"
echo "osver: $osver"
echo "old file_path is : $file_path"
file_path=$(echo "$file_path" | sed "s/$sys/${osver}/")
echo "new file_path is : $file_path"
```

But getting the output:

```
osver: amd64_linux26_rh5.64
old file_path is : /xxx/xxx/xxx/amd64_linux26_rh5/xxx
new file_path is : /xxx/xxx/xxx/amd64_linux26_rh5/xxx
```

I also have tried `file_path=$(echo "$file_path" | sed "s/$sys/${os}\.64/")` but did not the same output.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That output is still not what the script produces – the current version works for me.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616049/sed-command-not-accepting-sub-string-with-in-ksh ?